# Ansible: Include variables file under role/xyzrole/main.yml

Tags: ansible, roles

I have some variables that dont change and some that do from time to time.
I'd like my main.yml within the role to list all the static variables, for the dynamic variables I'd like to put them in a different file and just include the new file everytime there is a change.

Like this:

**main.yml:**

```
---
var1: somevalue
var2: anothervalue
var3:
  var3.1: somevalue that changes
  var3.2: anothervalue that changes
```

Instead of that, I'd like to do the following:

**main.yml:**

```
---
var1: somevalue
var2: anothervalue
invlude_vars: varsfile.yml
```

**varsfile.yml:**

```
---
var3:
  var3.1: somevalue that changes
  var3.2: anothervalue that changes
```

This way I dont have to touch main.yml but change varsfile.yml everytime there is any change.
I tried it, ends in following error:

```
fatal: [hostnamehidden]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'var3.1' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '.../tasks/main.yml': line 7, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Some tasks is getting executed here^ here\n"}
```

Any ideas? Is it possible to do this at all within the roles/rolename/vars/main.yml?

Comment: To be honest, it sounds like you're just doing it wrong.  If you have variables that change frequently, they should be set in the inventory, not in the role.

Comment: @Jack, thank you! Yes thats an option, but these variables that change and those do not change, hence I like them to be kept together. Thank you for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options depending on the exact use-case. For example, use the default values. Given the role

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/defaults/main.yml 
var1: somevalue
var2: anothervalue
var3:
  var3.1: "{{ somevalue_that_changes|default('UNDEFINED') }}"
  var3.2: "{{ anothervalue_that_changes|default('UNDEFINED') }}"

shell> cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml 
- debug:
    var: var3
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  roles:
    - role3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

TASK [role3 : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  var3:
    var3.1: UNDEFINED
    var3.2: UNDEFINED
```

---

If you define the variable, for example on the command-line, the playbook gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e somevalue_that_changes=XYZ

TASK [role3 : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  var3:
    var3.1: XYZ
    var3.2: UNDEFINED
```

---

Of course, it's possible to put the variables into a file and use the file in the playbook. For example

```yaml
shell> cat varsfile.yml 
somevalue_that_changes: XYZ
anothervalue_that_changes: 123

shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: localhost
  vars_files:
    - varsfile.yml
  roles:
    - role3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

TASK [role3 : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  var3:
    var3.1: XYZ
    var3.2: '123'
```

---

It's possible to include the data in the role instead of the playbook. For example

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml
- include_vars: varsfile.yml
- debug:
    var: var3
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml

TASK [role3 : debug] ****
ok: [localhost] => 
  var3:
    var3.1: XYZ
    var3.2: '123'
```

---

Q: **"*Separate the changing variables into another file and include them within vars/main.yml*"**

A: Use [lookup plugin file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#using-lookup-plugins). For example, put the changing variables into the file

```yaml
shell> cat files/varsfile.yml
var3.1: XYZ
var3.2: 123
```

Combine the changing variables from the file with the defaults

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/defaults/main.yml 
var1: somevalue
var2: anothervalue
var3_default:
  var3.1: "{{ somevalue_that_changes|default('UNDEFINED') }}"
  var3.2: "{{ anothervalue_that_changes|default('UNDEFINED') }}"

shell> cat roles/role3/vars/main.yml
var3: "{{ var3_default|combine(lookup('file', 'varsfile.yml')|from_yaml) }}"
```

Then, the debug task

```yaml
shell> cat roles/role3/tasks/main.yml
- debug:
    var: var3
```

gives

```yaml
  var3:
    var3.1: XYZ
    var3.2: 123
```

It's rather flexible. For example, if you omit var3.1

```yaml
shell> cat files/varsfile.yml
var3.2: 123
```

The result is

```yaml
  var3:
    var3.1: UNDEFINED
    var3.2: 123
```

In addition to this, you can still override the default values. For example,

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook playbook.yml -e somevalue_that_changes=ABC
```

gives

```yaml
  var3:
    var3.1: ABC
    var3.2: 123
```

Fit the defaults/vars, paths, and combinations to your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot as always, your answers are always well documented and tested. I was not wanting to include the vars in the tasks folder, thought it would not be purely ansible way, that is `roles/role3/vars/main.yml` has everything, I just thought by seperating the changing variables into another file and include them here within `vars/main.yml` so I can keep track of history of changes to the vars. That is all. Looks like include of anykind from within the main.yml of vars folder wont work in this case. Thanks once again.

Comment: It's possible to read files inside `vars/main`. I've updated the answer. If you have another issue open a new question. Thank you for the comments.

Comment: Thank you once again! The latest seems to be much better and more ansible way of role doing its thing. I will implement this one.